# Get style of KML feature in OL5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml, openlayers-5

I am trying to extract the style of a KML. It appears on screen fine, as if the style is embedded, but when I try to get the style object:

```
    var fs=new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(data);
    for (i=0;i<fs.length;++i) {                                             
        f=fs[i].clone();
        if (f.getStyle())
            os=f.getStyle();
            ...
```

It returns only some sort of function def:

ƒ (t,e){var i,r=c,n="";if(r){var o=t.getGeometry(); ...

Comment: To get a style from a style function you need to call the function.  `getStyle()` may return a style, array, or function.  `getStyleFunction()` will wrap styles in a function so `os=f.getStyleFunction()(f,1)` should always work (include an arbitrary resolution parameter although it's unlikely to be used)